# nested string.gmatch syntax format

Tags: string, lua, match

I am struggling with some nested gmatch functions (using Lua code equivalent)

Let's say I have (3) structures each improves random skill actions;

```
["building1"] = { effect = "+1 Improve Lifestyle, +1 Quell Unrest (Magic), random note"},
["building2"] = { effect = "+2 Hire Adventurers, +1 Trade Commodities"},
["building3"] = { effect = "just some random notes"}
```

For simplicity, I have a loop cycling through each record ... which captures the effect data into "sEffects".
Then, I try to split it up using gmatch ... to look for (plus sign) followed by (number) and (space).

I am able to split the text into lines using the following;

```
    for sLine in string.gmatch(sEffects, "([^,]+)") do
      nCount = nCount +1;
      Debug.chat("line " .. nCount .. " = " .. sLine);
```

which generates the following output;

```
line 1 = +1 Improve Lifestyle
line 2 = +1 Quell Unrest (Magic)
Line 3 = random note
Line 1 = +2 Hire Adventurers
Line 2 = +1 Trade Commodities
Line 1 = just some random notes
```

However, I need to split it into (bonus) and (skill) ... while excluding any line that doesnt start with "+"(number).

Something like this;

```
bonus=1, skill=Improve Lifestyle
bonus=1, skill=Quell Unrest (Magic)
bonus=2, skill=Hire Adventurers
bonus=1, skill=Trade Commodities
```

which captures the (bonus) and (skill) while ignoring all other data.

perhaps something like this (if I can figure out the gmatch syntax)

```
for bonus, skill in string.gmatch(sLine, "([^+%d]+)") do
  Debug.chat("bonus= " .. bonus);
  Debug.chat("skill= " .. skill);
end
```

How do I format the gmatch search so it does the following?

1. ignore any line without "+" in it
2. ignore spaces in front of the "+"
3. return the decimal after "+" sign as first variable
4. return the remainder of line after (+)(decimal)(space) as second variable

Comment: `local bonus, skill = sLine:match("%+(%d+)%s+(.*)")`

Answer (score 0):

Now that I stated the issue, think I found a way to work around it.

```
      local pos = string.find(sLine, "+");  
      if pos == nil then
        -- do nothing
      else
        local sEnd = string.len(sLine);
        nBonus = tonumber(string.sub(sLine, pos+1, pos +1))
        sAction = string.sub(sLine, pos+3, sEnd)
        Debug.chat("bonus=" .. nBonus .. ", skill=" .. sAction .. "]");
      end
```

First, I check to see if sLine contains a plus sign ... that solves #1

To solve #2 and #3 ... I use the returned position +1 to assign the nBonus

For #4 ... I can use position return +3 (so it skips the space after the number as well) ... and have it return everything up until end of line.

Now its returning the following;

```
bonus=1, skill=Improve Lifestyle
bonus=1, skill=Quell Unrest (Magic)
bonus=2, skill=Hire Adventurers
bonus=1, skill=Trade Commodities
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work, assuming none of the skill names have a comma in them.

```
for bonus,skill in str:gmatch('%+(%d+) ([^,]+)') do
  print(bonus, skill)
end

Result:
1   Improve Lifestyle
1   Quell Unrest (Magic)
```